# React Navigation: Warning react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

**What intended doing**

1. ***create react-native with expo***
2. ***add React Navigation***

> The first work well
>
> the **second task have warnings**

**Steps in the Second task**

1. Install React Navigation

   npm install react-navigation --legacy-peer-deps
2. Install Dependencies

   expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
3. Install React Navigation Stack

   npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view --legacy-peer-deps
4. Start the app and clear cache with `expo r -c`

**Warning Logs**

Compiled with warnings.
C:/Users/GBENGE AONDOAKULA/Documents/Node/food/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'ComposedGestureType' (reexported as 'ComposedGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/gestureComposition'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'ComposedGestureType' (reexported as 'ComposedGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/gestureComposition'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'ExclusiveGestureType' (reexported as 'ExclusiveGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/gestureComposition'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'FlingGestureType' (reexported as 'FlingGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/flingGesture'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'ForceTouchGestureType' (reexported as 'ForceTouchGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/forceTouchGesture'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'GestureStateManagerType' (reexported as 'GestureStateManager') was not found in './handlers/gestures/gestureStateManager'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'LongPressGestureType' (reexported as 'LongPressGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/longPressGesture'

node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js
"export 'ManualGestureType' (reexported as 'ManualGesture') was not found in './handlers/gestures/manualGesture'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the version of `react-native-gesture-handler` to `1.10.3`.
It works for me.

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler@1.10.3
```

Comment: **running the web throw no error as rightly said**   But  _I perform the above cmd and I got  this When I ran_  `expo start`            "Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - react-native-gesture-handler - expected version: ~2.1.0 - actual version installed: 1.10.3
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...] "          @AliRehman7141 Thanks

Comment: **Here is warning using git bash cmd. The Above was normal window cmd not PowerShell**

There seem to be a transient problem with Expo servers, using the cache                 d dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in                  your project.